# How to increase goldfish color?

Tags: aquarium, diet, goldfish, biology

I was fooled a bit when buying this one fish, when the fish arrived it looks not so appealing to me... is there something I could do to brighten it's color or should I just ask for a bit refund?

I bought it for around $27.5, the same price as the black (different seller), expecting to be as good. I like the body, curve, face, but the color is not so good.

The middle:
[image]

Edit : the seller is willing to refund a bit (just a bit) so, is there anything that can change it's color?

This is what I am expecting, perhaps different for top view and side view.
Maybe it's also me that's wrong, lol:
[image]

Comment: I know for Koi , and expect it is true for gold fish; One of the largest costs is sorting young fish by color to determine which ones have good enough color to grow out . The rest are disposed of. It looks to me like this breeder saved less colorful fish than most breeders. The color will not change significantly with age or condition.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to improve a fish color for real is with good food with beta carotene, I remember tetra brand having some of them. You can check deeper information about that here: http://www.seacolors.eu/images/NPR_61_46-49.pdf

Is not going to be magic and will take some time.

You can also use home made food but that's a more complex task as well as more cleaning demanding.

Comment: Do you know the reason why the color looks like that? only gene or other reasons?

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/w2kXJMcrp4b5UovD7 this is the only color enhancer by Tetra , in my country. Other food is red maggot said : high protein and beta carotene.

Comment: I remember a time where I had Discus on the same tank than Goldfish and they tended to eat my discus food (this one : https://www.aquariumkingdom.com.au/tetra-tetracolor-tropical-granules-300g) their color was extreme. Anyway I don't recommend it as for goldfish is like eternal summer and accelerated metabolism. Good food and low stress with excellent water conditions will do the job for your goldfish to look awesome.

Comment: But your goldfish eat that and got extreme color?

Comment: Quite good yes, super orange and super black and golden. I'll try to find some pictures but like I said, that's food for cichlids who has a different metabolism and food needs than carassius